# Error response from daemon: pull access denied for TestDockerImage

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am new to docker and Jenkins2.
I am trying to pull docker image from private docker repository.

```
pipeline {
         agent{
            docker{
                image "PrivateRepo/Test"
                args "--username testUser --password pass -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace:/home --env "
            }
        }
        stages {
                .
                .
                .
               }
 }
```

when I run Jenkins file it gives me below error

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for PrivateRepo/Test, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Where do I give docker credential or how can I provide access to repository.

Comment: your user on the jenkins server should have the rights to manage docker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registry "PrivateRepo" requires a login to all pulling images from it. If you have access to the machine where jenkins is running, you can simply do that by executing:

```
docker login PrivateRepo
```

Alternatively, you can do it from jenkins as described in [here](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/CLOUD/Configuring+Docker+Credentials+in+Jenkins+Jobs).

Answer (score 9):

Faced the similar problem while pulling the nginx image with command:

> docker run --rm -p 8088:80 ngnix

Actualy, i was providing the wrong image name and it does not report for wrong image and displayed the above message.And hence after correcting the image name using command

> docker run --rm -p 8088:80 nginx

It worked fine after this change.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had not loaded the particular image into docker:

```
sudo docker load -i <image_name>
```

solved my issue